# C# handling of images - is this best for memory usage?

Tags: c#, image, memory-optimization

I am working with a system that needs to consume product images uploaded by employees and resize them / add white padding to the sides to create square images to be consumed by our e-commerce site.  I'm attempting to keep things somewhat light on the memory usage because this will live in a windows service on an azure vm.  I know there are better solutions, but that's what I'm given as a platform.  I also don't want to use 3rd party libraries.

The following code is what I have so far.  Please, pick it apart and let me know if i'm making any mistakes.

```
public static Image ImageToFixedSize(Image originalImage, int width, int height)
{
    Graphics graphicController = null;

    try
    {
        if (originalImage != null)
        {
            int sourceWidth = originalImage.Width;
            int sourceHeight = originalImage.Height;
            int destX = 0;
            int destY = 0;

            float percent = 0;
            float percentW = 0;
            float percentH = 0;

            percentW = width / (float)sourceWidth;
            percentH = height / (float)sourceHeight;
            if (percentH < percentW)
            {
                percent = percentH;
                destX = Convert.ToInt16((width - (sourceWidth * percent)) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                percent = percentW;
                destY = Convert.ToInt16((height - (sourceHeight * percent)) / 2);
            }

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * percent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent);

            Bitmap tempPhoto = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            tempPhoto.SetResolution(originalImage.HorizontalResolution, originalImage.VerticalResolution);
            graphicController = Graphics.FromImage(tempPhoto);
            graphicController.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);

            // The chances of hitting this ONE SPECIFIC COLOR are very slim
            graphicController.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphicController.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphicController.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicController.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            graphicController.DrawImage(
                originalImage,
                new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(1, 1, sourceWidth - 1, sourceHeight - 1),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            return tempPhoto;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        graphicController.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Reversing the condition of `if (originalImage != null)` and returning early will remove one level of indentation. The less indentation some code shows the easier to read it will become.
- `catch` to just rethrow, althought you did it in the correct way, doesn't buy you anything. Just remove the `try..catch..finally` and enclose the usage of `graphics` with an `usage` block.
- Althought the code is mostly named well, one could stumble over `tempPhoto` and can't figure out at first glance wether this object is important or just temporary.
- You can cast e.g `((width - (sourceWidth * percent)) / 2)` directly to `int` you don't need a call to `Convert.ToInt16()` here.
- `percentW` and `percentH` are first defined and on the next lines you assign a value to them. You should do it just at the declaration to save some (superflous) lines of code.
- Instead of `graphicController.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);` you should use `graphicController.Clear(Color.White);` which is easier to read.
- Comments, when used, should state, in a clear and understandable way, why the code is written as it is. I don't get the comment `// The chances of hitting this ONE SPECIFIC COLOR are very slim`. Where could be a problem with the code to make this comment justified?
- The code validates the `Image originalImage` method parameter, but allows "illegal" values for `int width` and `int height`.

Implementing most of the mentioned points (validation is for you) will lead to

```
public static Image ImageToFixedSize(Image originalImage, int width, int height)
{
    if (originalImage == null) { return null; }

    int sourceWidth = originalImage.Width;
    int sourceHeight = originalImage.Height;
    int destX = 0;
    int destY = 0;

    float percent = 0;
    float percentW = width / (float)sourceWidth;
    float percentH = height / (float)sourceHeight;

    if (percentH < percentW)
    {
        percent = percentH;
        destX = (int)((width - (sourceWidth * percent)) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        percent = percentW;
        destY = (int)((height - (sourceHeight * percent)) / 2);
    }

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * percent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent);

    Bitmap fixedSizedImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    fixedSizedImage.SetResolution(originalImage.HorizontalResolution, originalImage.VerticalResolution);

    using (Graphics graphicController = Graphics.FromImage(fixedSizedImage))
    {
        graphicController.Clear(Color.White);

        // The chances of hitting this ONE SPECIFIC COLOR are very slim
        graphicController.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphicController.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphicController.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphicController.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        graphicController.DrawImage(
            originalImage,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(1, 1, sourceWidth - 1, sourceHeight - 1),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return fixedSizedImage;

}
```

Comment: I agree with almost everything you stated, thank you for your assistance.  I want to ask, about the casting of sourceWidth / sourceHeight... My environment is warning me about a 'Possible loss of fraction'.  Thoughts?

Comment: Well, my VS 2017 doesn't show a warning but you are right. One of the terms should be `float`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Just a note on the `using`: With the current C# version, you can just write `using var graphicsController = Graphics.FromImage(...);` without having a block after. It will automatically be disposed once the enclosing scope is finished. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)